# When did Anakin Skywalker learn that Palpatine is a Dark Lord of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In Episode III, when he sees Mace Windu being electrocuted then thrown out of the window he seems shocked, but not surprised, and readily joins Palpatine, turning to the dark side.

When Palpatine tells him about Darth Plagueis, it's a pretty strong hint, so perhaps at this point he was already aware. But in Episode II, he seems to be oblivious of this fact. So when exactly does he learn about Palpatine's true identity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Were you perhaps asleep during the scene in Episode III where Palpatine takes Anakin into his secret chamber of Sith and tells him everything?

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it by seconds.

Comment: Gotta be quick around here. In fairness I would have been even quicker had I not spent nearly a minute trying to write a witty header.

Comment: "Were you perhaps asleep" is a good one, because I wouldn't blame him one bit.

Comment: I probably was, or this scene wasn't in the original theatrical release, because I could swear it's the first time I see it.

Comment: Could've been during a bathroom break

Comment: That scene was definitely in the theatrical release, I remember the hallway scene with the weird bas-relief mural as one of my favorite scenes of the movie when I first saw it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Richard, by the way. This is a great scene and Ian McDiarmid is a fantastic actor, I heard he's a classically trained Shakespearean actor, so that's why he's able to make up for Hayden's stiff underwhelming performance.